# JAVAFX, Countdown doesn't work

Tags: java, javafx, timeunit

The count down does not work. I'm triggering it through a button.

```
public void startCountDown() {
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
        public void run() {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               countDown--;
                countDownText.setText("Time left:" + countDown);

                if (countDown < 0)
                    timer.cancel();
          }
        });
    }
    }, 1000); //Every 1 second
}
```

The countDown variable is set to 60, so the countdown starts at 60

EDIT: The countdown gets stuck at 59 seconds, countDown is an int. No errors. And countDownText is declared as text.

```
@FXML
private Text countDownText;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "does not work"? Does it generate errors? Or does it just not do what you want? It would probably also be helpful to edit your question to show (at least) the declarations of `countDown` and `countDownText`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's more than 1 timer class, but I assume you used java.util.Timer

Examining the API shows you used this method:

```
public void schedule(TimerTask task,
            long delay)

Schedules the specified task for execution after the specified delay.

Parameters:
    task - task to be scheduled.
    delay - delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed.
Throws:
    IllegalArgumentException - if delay is negative, or delay + System.currentTimeMillis() is negative.
    IllegalStateException - if task was already scheduled or cancelled, timer was cancelled, or timer thread terminated.
    NullPointerException - if task is null
```

So your program waits 1 second then executes the run() method, but **does not repeat**. To make it repeat, you need to use this method:

```
public void schedule(TimerTask task,
            long delay,
            long period)

Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-delay execution, beginning after the specified delay. Subsequent executions take place at approximately regular intervals separated by the specified period.

In fixed-delay execution, each execution is scheduled relative to the actual execution time of the previous execution. If an execution is delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background activity), subsequent executions will be delayed as well. In the long run, the frequency of execution will generally be slightly lower than the reciprocal of the specified period (assuming the system clock underlying Object.wait(long) is accurate).

Fixed-delay execution is appropriate for recurring activities that require "smoothness." In other words, it is appropriate for activities where it is more important to keep the frequency accurate in the short run than in the long run. This includes most animation tasks, such as blinking a cursor at regular intervals. It also includes tasks wherein regular activity is performed in response to human input, such as automatically repeating a character as long as a key is held down.

Parameters:
    task - task to be scheduled.
    delay - delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed.
    period - time in milliseconds between successive task executions.
Throws:
    IllegalArgumentException - if delay < 0, or delay + System.currentTimeMillis() < 0, or period <= 0
    IllegalStateException - if task was already scheduled or cancelled, timer was cancelled, or timer thread terminated.
    NullPointerException - if task is null
```

You can view the complete documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long%29

Here is what I think is correct code:

```
public void startCountDown() {
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
        public void run() {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               countDown--;
                countDownText.setText("Time left:" + countDown);

                if (countDown < 0)
                    timer.cancel();
          }
        });
    }
    }, 1000, 1000); //Every 1 second
}
```